# Does GQLAlchemy support explicit transactions?

Tags: memgraphdb

Does GQLAlchemy support explicit transactions? I want to start a transaction with the `BEGIN;` query and execute the following queries as a part of a single transaction. Also, I need to commit successful transactions by executing the `COMMIT;` query. I tried doing that with GQLAlchemy and I was not successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GQLAlchemy currently (version 1.4) does not support explicit transactions. Currently, you can run explicit transactions with [pymgclient](https://github.com/memgraph/pymgclient), on top of which GQLAlchemy is built, and example of that can be found in README file on the repository.